How to use react-native-callkeep
After following the installation steps from the docs for android, at the end , it tells to add this block of code in index.android.js:
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('RNCallKeepBackgroundMessage', () => ({ name, callUUID, handle }) => {
  // Make your call here
  
  return Promise.resolve();
});

But as we have a combined index.js now for both android and iOS, so i added this in the index.js as :
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask(
  'RNCallKeepBackgroundMessage',
  () =>
    ({ name, callUUID, handle }) => {
      console.warn('RNCallKeepBackgroundMessage', name, callUUID, handle);
      const callkeep = new CallKeep();
      callkeep.onIncomingCall({ callUUID, handle });

      return Promise.resolve();
    },
);

But this is never called, I never get any console warn. When exactly is the headlessJs registered and how does it actually work.
